# Pikaday Datepicker too many recursions / stack overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs, pikaday

I've come across this issue with [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)

I have a simple select field, that runs some ajax and passes a set of blackout dates to the pikaday datepicker. However, re-building pikaday's datepicker is throwing a re-instancing loop error which occurs when you re-build a pikaday on the same element twice within the DOM.

I have googled around and found some help on the matter
https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/382

```
// Destroy it at some point in the future - 
// NOT really working or helping the loop issue
$('.somefield').pikaday('destroy');
```

and this being the most helpful one of all

https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/429

http://codepen.io/thephpjo/pen/pjqavp?editors=1111

The above codepen does a great job showing the double instance on single element issue using

```
onSelect: function() {
     console.log('pong')
}
```

That said, the solutions aren't helping my issue. I'm really just hoping i'm doing something completely wrong here, as i need to figure out this "bug".

That said, i've got my simple version example of this running on codepen.

Please note, that the select field must re-build the pikaday each time as a new set of dates will be passed. So the way to see the bug in action, is select a dropdown choice, pick a date via pikaday-datepicker then change the dropdown choice once more and use the datepicker again. Pay close attention to the console.

You'll see how many times it runs the "Hello Again!". This causes the datepicker to hang, sometimes permanently and throws the Too many recursions / Stack Overflow errors.

Simplified pikaday to display bug: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpWRZL?editors=1111

Comment: In your codepen change `minDate: new Date(moment().add(1, 'days'))` to `minDate: moment().add(1, 'days').toDate()`. I'm not sure if it is the only issue here, but it is the right way to get a Date object from a moment object.

Comment: Thanks, however that's not the issue i'm trying to solve. But much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the way to avoid this silly bug is to completely .remove() the element you're applying the pikaday datepicker to, then just rebuild the element via .append() and voila, it's properly reset and a new datepicker can be applied.